# recuperar fecha del dia siguiente

Tags: php, mysql

tengo esta funcion en donde recupero la fecha del dia actual para insertarlo en una tabla de registros, como podria hacer para que insertara el dia siguiente.

```html
 public function ReservationData(){
  $this->name = "";
  $this->message = "";
  $this->lastname = "";
  $this->email = "";
  $this->password = "";
  $this->created_at = "NOW()";
  $this->date_at = "NOW()";
 }
```

intente con now() + 1; pero no funciono

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de usar la función `NOW()` puedes agregar lo siguiente

```
+ INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Quedando tu `SELECT` del modo siguiente

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Lo que te va a retornar como resultado lo siguiente

```
+------------------------+
| NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY |
+------------------------+
| 2019-01-17 15:41:48    |
+------------------------+
```

El uso de `INTERVAL 1 DAY` equivale a un rango de 24 hrs.

Aqui tienes mas información al respecto [Fechas y su manejo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar otra opción con la función date de php

ejemplo:

```
$sig=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que now() devuelve un objeto de tipo DateTime (lo más lógico, pues es la clase designada en PHP para las fechas), podrías hacer uso de el método add:

```
<?php
$fecha= new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$fecha->add(new DateInterval('PT10H30S')); // uso del método mencionado
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$fecha = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$fecha->add(new DateInterval('P7Y5M4DT4H3M2S')); 
// Y = year, M = month y asi sucesivamente, para añadir dias sería D - new DateInterval('P4D'). (La P siempre está ahí)

echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

2000-01-01 10:00:30
2007-06-05 04:03:02
```

Puedes investigar más utilidades de esta clase aquí (fuente) : http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php